# Laravel 9 - ErrorException: Undefined variable $order_id while sending mail

Tags: php, laravel

Hello in my laravel application i have a moment when the user is notified on mail when tha order is complete.

`
In my controller i have:

```
Mail::to('test@mail')->send(new OrderSuccess($id));

// $id is a string
```

in mail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderSuccess extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $order_id;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($order_id)
    {
        $this->order_id = $order_id;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.ordermail')
                    ->with([
                        'order_id' => $this->order_id
                    ]);
    }
}
```

In mail blade template:

```
Test order n. {{ $order_id }}
```

But i'm getting a failed job that shows this error

ErrorException: Undefined variable $order_id in C:\Users...

What am i doing wrong?

`

Comment: if u dd the id before calling `Mail::to('m.miscischia@buffetti.it')->send(new OrderSuccess($id));`, what u get?

Comment: as i wrote i already know that $id is a string

Comment: is not a string, is an undefined variable

Comment: Your code looks correct. Have you tried to restart your queue worker?

Comment: @ericmp i dd it before and for make you sure that it's a string : $id = $request->input('order_id');

Comment: @stefket thank you very much that was the issue! Do you know why also?

Comment: @userpc1000 Perhaps you have added the `->with(...)` code after starting the queue worker? 

Queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory.

Comment: @userpc1000 thanks for trying the dd! is the 1st thing u have to try to debug

Comment: @stefket ah ok understand, thank you! p.s. if you reply to the question i rate it :)

Comment: there are 2 ways to use the queue, with `listen` or `work` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#the-queue-work-command, during developement it is probably best to use listen because of the changes happening in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Try to restart your queue worker.

Queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory.

Comment: This was the solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below given code.

```
return $this->view('mails.ordermail',['order_id' => $this->order_id]);
```